# Bundle Product Price Not Updating On Product Page When Selecting Options

Tags: magento2.2.3, bundle-product

I have created a bundle product with 2 options.

One option is a dropdown menu (required).

The 2nd option is a checkbox (required).

When I select my options the price in the right column is not updated.

Once added to cart the price reflected is correct.

Magento version is 2.2.3

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please check the browser console for any JS error.

Comment: Facing same issue please share the way you solved..

Comment: @PritamInfo24 I have same problem there is no error in console

Answer (score 4):

I think you are using a custom Magento theme or Custom Bundle product module, right?

If yes, you should debug on your browser to detect what the issue is. Steps to debug (Chrome):

1. Inspect element (Ctrl+Shift+I), select sources tab and try to find **price-bundle.js** (Ctrl+O): 
   [image]
2. Find _onBundleOptionChanged function and add a breakpoint at the begin of the function:

[image]

3. Change product option, and then you can find what the wrong is

[image]

Sorry, this is not a core issue, so I can only suggest you steps to troubleshoot your problem

Regards